# Image not correctly filling a UIImageView in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to construct a tableView where the first cell is a square image the same width as the screen, but am having difficulties. Currently the UIImageView is the correct width, but there the image is not filling the UIImageView.

Below are how the image appears on iPhone 6 and iPad 2 (I set the UIImageView background to blue to show that the UIImageView is sized correctly)

[image: iPhone 6] 
[image: iPad 2]

So far, I have tried:

1. Changing from "Scale To Fill" to "Aspect Fill" (That changed nothing so I kept it "Scale To Fill")
2. Changing the Autolayout constraints on the UIImageView (but it seems to be laid out correctly, the image is just not filling it)
3. Changing the tableview contentInset property
4. Checking the UIImageView's borders (postImageView.layer.borderWidth) and ensuring it was 0 (it was)
5. Searching my project to ensure the contentMode was not set programmatically somewhere else (it wasn't)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update 1

I printed the frames of both the cell and UIImageView

```
print("cell: \(self.frame)")
print("image: \(postImageView.frame)")
```

Which resulted in (on iPad 2 Simulator)

```
cell: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 769.0)
image: (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 768.0)
```

#### Update 2

All the images are saved as 640x640 square images.

I have been able to get a UIImage to correctly size on the page before (which is a feed of images), however, when clicking into the detail view the images is incorrectly sized.
When I tap on an image in the homefeed (TableView inside a NavigationController)
[image: Home Feed Screenshot]

I get the detail ViewController pushed onto the NavigationController, but the image doesn't seem to fill the UIImageView...
[image: Detail View Screenshot]

Comment: Try printing the image view's frame and printing the cell's frame.

Comment: I did that `print("cell width: \(self.frame.width)") print("image width: \(postImageView.frame.width)")` and the result was "cell width: 383.0
image width: 383.0" which is what I expected.

Comment: you can just say print(cell.frame) print(cell.imageView.frame). And add what's printed to your question.

Comment: How and where are you setting the image? Do you know the dimensions of the image?

Comment: I set the image in the tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath function, but there is logic there since the first cell is the square image and then cell's after that are user comment sells (users can comment on images). I also updated the post above with more details. Thanks for the quick reply @beyowulf